# How to setup ds4drv as DAEMON on Ubuntu?

Tags: services, gamepad

I have a Dualshock 4 controller, Kubuntu 15.10, and ds4drv installed. Everything is working fine, but I would like that ds4drv works as a daemon.

How can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions from this answer ==> https://askubuntu.com/a/188148/483417

Use this file ==> https://gist.github.com/mariosotil/ed4293660c600fbe24b0

Answer (score -1):

Found this trying to get mine running completely

[image]

https://github.com/chrippa/ds4drv

https://github.com/chrippa/ds4drv/blob/master/ds4drv.conf!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This answer doesn't seem to actually explain what you did to get the dualshock controller working. If you explain the configuration changes you made, your answer will be of higher quality.