# Cannot manually stop/restart a upstart service on Ubuntu14/GCE

Tags: java, upstart

I have a `/etc/init/myservice.conf`. On reboot, it's up and running with no issues. The service is a java web server, e.g.:

```
java -jar myhttpserver.jar
```

But! I cannot manually stop or restart the service. If I do:

```
service myservice stop
```

Then the terminal hangs. If I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and try again, it tells me `stop: Job has already been stopped: myservice`. I think it's lying because I can still access the it using a web browser. `initctl list` shows this:

```
myservice stop/killed, process 1303
```

Why it cannot be stopped? How do I manually restart it? I want to test the sever by replacing the jar and restarting service.

FWIW, it's a Google Compute Engine instance with Ubuntu 14. The conf file:

```
description "server instances"
author "Me"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on shutdown

#Respawn the process if it crashes
respawn
#If it respawns more than 10 times in 5 seconds stop
respawn limit 10 5

expect fork

script
    logPath="/var/log/myservice"
    mkdir -p $logPath

    logFile="/"$logPath"/"$(date +'%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')
    java -cp /home/myuser/dev.jar com.myservice.Main dev > $logFile"_dev_std" 2> $logFile"_dev_err"
end script
```

Comment: Are you literally running `service stop myservice`?

Comment: Oops should be service myservice stop

Comment: The issue I'm concerned about is whether or not you are literally using `myservice` (which is a placeholder for the service you are trying to control, not an actual service).

Comment: I am literally using myservice. So what should I use for the real service?

Comment: Ah, this is why I was confused. How long have you waited during that terminal hang?

Comment: About half a minute?

Comment: What exactly is in the `conf` file? It seems like just the Java exec line wouldn't work. http://askubuntu.com/questions/18802/how-to-correctly-add-a-custom-daemon-to-init-d

Comment: Updated the question with conf file.